# How to continue QTCaptureSession at login screen?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, video-streaming, qtkit

I've got a program I have written which creates a QTCaptureSession, and is able to receive and process image frames.  The problem is when I switch to the login screen the iSight LED goes off and I don't get any frames.  As soon as I log back in the frames start arriving again, and I see no indication of errors in my program.

This is a problem because I want to use the built-in iSight on my Mac for security purposes, and obviously leaving an unattended computer without going to the login screen is in itself a security problem.

How do I continue the capture, regardless of the state of the user session?

Running OS X 10.7.4.

Comment: What do you mean by 'switch to the login screen'? Could you please provide more details on how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Fast-user switching is enabled, so while the program is running, I can go to the upper-right corner and click on my name, which pulls down a menu with the various login names available, and "Login Window".  I select this last option, and it takes me to the login screen.  As soon as it switches to this screen, I no longer receive frames.

Comment: I see what you mean. If you are talking about security you can enable 'Require password for sleep and screen saver' option. Turning on the screen saver through one of the hot corners will allow you to lock the computer. Login screen in this case does not stop capture session, so you can see who tried to access the computer while you were away. But if you switch to another user account, the capture session stops working, you are right. I guess Apple did this on purpose to make it impossible for one account to spy on other one. Or maybe they had performance optimisation in mind. Who knows.